# How do I warn a user of unsaved changes before leaving a page in Vue

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

I have an `UnsavedChangesModal` as a component that needs to be launched when the user tries to leave the page when he has unsaved changes in the input fields (I have three input fields in the page).

```
components: {
    UnsavedChangesModal
},
mounted() {
    window.onbeforeunload = '';
},
methods: {
   alertChanges() {

   }
}
```

Comment: vue-router have `beforeRouteLeave` hook

Comment: 1. You can use vue lifecycle method - "beforeDestroy " hook as well and add a popup/dailog box before leaving page.

2 . You can use Vue-router BeforerouteLeave or use watch property on path.

Answer (score 87, accepted):

Assuming you're using [vue-router](https://router.vuejs.org/) (and you probably should be), then you'll want to use the `beforeRouteLeave` guard. [The documentation](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#the-full-navigation-resolution-flow) even gives an example of this exact situation:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from , next) {
  const answer = window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!')
  if (answer) {
    next()
  } else {
    next(false)
  }
}
```

That can be added directly right on your component:

```
components: { ... },
mounted: { ... }
methods: { ... },
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) { ... }
```

Comment: Does this works when navigating to another website / closing the browser tab as well?

Comment: @ZiadAkiki it doesn't block them for me no.

Comment: upvoted! what to do if I am not using the Vue router

Comment: If you aren't using vue router then youll have to just bind to the window with: `window.onbeforeunload = () => 'Are you sure you want to leave?'`

Comment: @jpschroeder how can be it used for such a scenario? 
Let's say you have a route /settings/:productId then made changes for that selected product and from drop down tried to to select another product then how can dialog be implemented in this case? Since only id was changed.
Because above solution didn't work.

Comment: If anyone else reads this and wants a working Vue example which works even when closing the page. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551646/8150685)

Comment: @NewTechLover you can handle using "beforeRouteUpdate" method for dynamic route params

Comment: It wont work for component which are included in routing configuration.

Comment: Anyone figure out how to better handle or suggest to user that they need to allow popups for window.confirm("message")? When I try to use this solution I see chrome blocks it. I see the following in the dev console: "Blocked confirm('Do you really want to leave? You have unsaved changes!') during beforeunload"

Answer (score 22):

These answers only cover navigation within Vue.  If the user refreshes the page or navigates to a different site, that will not be caught.  So you also need something like:

```
window.onbeforeunload = () => (this.unsavedChanges ? true : null);
```

Comment: But how we are going to use this in vue.js. Can you please five an example

Comment: If anyone else reads this and wants a working Vue example [see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56551646/8150685).

Answer (score 5):

Are you using vue-router?  I would look into navigation guards. I keep them in mind, but haven't used them myself yet.  Here's the documentation on them: https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html

Comment: Does this guard against refreshing the page though?

Comment: What if we dont want to use vue-router?

Comment: @christostsang You can try using life cycle hooks like: `beforeDestory`