# How can I mimic onbeforeunload in a Vue.js 2 application?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have a Vue component that is tracking when it is "dirty" (e.g. unsaved). I would like to warn the user before they browse away from the current form if they have unsaved data. In a typical web application you could use `onbeforeunload`. I've attempted to use it in mounted like this:

```
mounted: function(){
  window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    return self.form_dirty ? "If you leave this page you will lose your unsaved changes." : null;
  }
}
```

However this doesn't work when using Vue Router. It will let you navigate down as many router links as you would like. As soon as you try to close the window or navigate to a *real* link, it will warn you.

Is there a way to replicate `onbeforeunload` in a Vue application for normal links as well as router links?

Comment: [beforeDestroy()](https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy) on the component.

Comment: @tao afaik you cannot cancel the destroy process inside `beforeDestroy` by returning false or the like

Comment: @phil294, no. you can't. It wouldn't make any sense. Think about it: you have a bunch of list elements (Vue components), one for each item in some data array. And you update the array. Some of your elements are gone from data. Now, do you really want your components to go: *"... actually, I think I'm gonna linger in DOM for a little longer. I protest and I won't be destroyed, OK? Let me call my lawyer! Or was it layer?"*

Answer (score 50, accepted):

Use the `beforeRouteLeave` [in-component guard](https://router.vuejs.org/guide/advanced/navigation-guards.html#in-component-guards) along with the [`beforeunload`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event) event.

> The leave guard is usually used to prevent the user from accidentally
> leaving the route with unsaved edits. The navigation can be canceled
> by calling next(false).

In your component definition do the following:

```
beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
  // If the form is dirty and the user did not confirm leave,
  // prevent losing unsaved changes by canceling navigation
  if (this.confirmStayInDirtyForm()){
    next(false)
  } else {
    // Navigate to next view
    next()
  }
},

created() {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeWindowUnload)
},

beforeDestroy() {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeWindowUnload)
},

methods: {
  confirmLeave() {
    return window.confirm('Do you really want to leave? you have unsaved changes!')
  },

  confirmStayInDirtyForm() {
    return this.form_dirty && !this.confirmLeave()
  },

  beforeWindowUnload(e) {
    if (this.confirmStayInDirtyForm()) {
      // Cancel the event
      e.preventDefault()
      // Chrome requires returnValue to be set
      e.returnValue = ''
    }   
  },
},
```

Comment: I don’t think this satisfies the requirement to confirm window closing like onbeforeunload... any way to incorporate that?

Comment: @dubloons I misread your question, use the `in-component` guard to handle route changes and the `beforeunload` event for when the user tries to close the window.

Comment: Anyone figure out how to better handle or suggest to user that they need to allow popups for `window.confirm("message")`?  When I try to use this solution I see chrome blocks it.  I see the following in the dev console: "Blocked confirm('Do you really want to leave? You have unsaved changes!') during beforeunload"

Answer (score 1):

The simplest solution to mimic this fully is as follow:

```
{
  methods: {
    beforeWindowUnload (e) {
      if (this.form_dirty) {
        e.preventDefault()
        e.returnValue = ''
      }
    }
  },
  beforeRouteLeave (to, from, next) {
    if (this.form_dirty) {
      next(false)
      window.location = to.path // this is the trick
    } else {
      next()
    }
  },
  created () {
    window.addEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeWindowUnload)
  },
  beforeDestroy () {
    window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', this.beforeWindowUnload)
  }
}
```