# Show popup about unsaved changes before leaving the component

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How do I show a custom pop up to alert about unsaved changes in a vue component before leaving the component? For example: If there is some page in which we have a cart (vue component) in which items are added but not saved, how do I show a custom modal to warn the user before leaving to a different component without a route change?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I mimic onbeforeunload in a Vue.js 2 application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56550164/how-can-i-mimic-onbeforeunload-in-a-vue-js-2-application)

Comment: https://vuejs.org/v2/api/#beforeDestroy

Comment: @Sumurai8  in my use case i don't have the route changes to make use of How can I mimic onbeforeunload in a Vue.js 2 application?

Comment: @Sumurai8 consider a tab switch without any page rerending. My use case is somthing like that

Comment: @StephenThomas tried with beforeDestroy life cycle hook , it will not show up the modal as the modal component is also present in the same component and the screen cannot be hold on at that state.

Comment: @Prashant In that case we need a [mcve]